# Error en consulta preparada de mysqli en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buen día a la comunidad.
Tengo la siguiente función:

```
function insertar_producto_carrito($id_producto,$cantidad,$conexion){
    try{
        $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("insert into carrito(id_producto,cantidad)values(?,?)");
        if($sentencia){
            $sentencia->bind_param("ii",$id_producto,$cantidad);
            $sentencia->excecute();
            $sentencia->close();
            cerrar_conexion($conexion);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

y al llamarla me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::excecute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda-virtual\admin\general\funciones.php:132 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda-virtual\admin\ajax\carrito.php(7): insertar_producto_carrito('1', 1, Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda-virtual\admin\general\funciones.php on line 132
```

ya revise los parámetros del método y todo funciona a la perfección, la verdad ya hice todo lo que esta a mi alcance sin éxito, si alguien tiene idea de que puede ser, se los agradecería mucho, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes un error de sintaxis:

debe escribir:

```
$sentencia->execute(); // OK
// $sentencia->excecute(); // esto tienes tú
```

Comment: perfecto gracias, como no me di cuenta

Comment: a todos no ha pasado, saludos!